# What are the possible advantages of using the "static" directive outside of a class?

Tags: c++, c++11, static

I've been doing some experimenting with function libraries and namespaces. I noticed that you can declare a function in a namespace as `static`, although it is not within a class declaration:

**hpp:**

```
ANameSpace
{

    static void aFunc();

};
```

**cpp:**

```
ANameSpace
{

    static void aFunc()
    {
        std::cout<<"Static function called"<<std::endl;
    }

};
```

I understand the concept of `static` class members and how they can be very useful, but are there any particular advantages to using `static` outside a class?

***Note:*** *I cast the final vote to close this question (can't delete because there is an answer) because the reference cited as dup, although it is much broader in scope, contains a detailed discussion of `static`. But I'm not sure if it exactly answers the question as I have rephrased it now.*

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/22541240/1382251 for a detailed description of the usage of `static`.

Comment: Or see [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `static` global function is visible only in the scope of the file. This is probably due to C compatibility, where this was also possible.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22540877/why-function-parameters-can-not-be-static/22541240#22541240) sums up every possible use of static pretty well.